# What is different in Rad mode in OlliOlli?

Tags: olliolli

I haven't unlocked it yet, but what is different in Rad mode?  I can only assume it's more difficult considering you unlock it after you beat the pro challenges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [PlaystationTrophies guide](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/game/olliolli/guide/) states the following (emphasis mine):

> Rad Mode unlocks once you have completed all five challenges in every level in both Amateur and Pro modes. **Unlike the other difficulties, this mode doesn't have any challenges. Instead, you will need to revisit all fifty levels that you have already completed and go through them again while landing only perfect combos and grinds.** This means that if you ever hit a trick or grind that is below perfect execution, you will automatically face plant and have to start over. While this is no easy feat, you will have gotten into a good rhythm from playing through the previous modes where getting perfect grinds and tricks should not be too bad.
>
> Luckily, there are no score or challenge requirements in Rad Mode. For the most part, it is recommended that you just go through the whole stage using ollies and any basic grind through. This will make it easier to focus on landing the tricks instead of doing anything fancy. It can also be easier at times to just ignore hopping on certain rails all together if the terrain is flat.
>
> You will learn that some levels are tougher than others due to specific jumps. There are a few levels in the junkyard and the port that can seem a lot harder than the rest. It is important to take it slow and figure out a pattern that works for you to hit specific jumps. It is always better to take it slow and look at a specific jump that you might be overshooting and determine what is the best way for your play style to land that jump next time around.

Comment: Ah, ok.  So it's like Metal Gear Solid European Extreme mode.